# Mod_Rewrite Masking Fails on Protocol Switching

Tags: mod-rewrite

Firstly let me tell you im greener than green when it comes to mod-rewriting this might be normal behaviour but i am looking for a way to stop it.

```
RewriteRule ^Network-Status/$ ./serverstatus.php [L,NC]
```

This is my Rewrite rule, What i expect this to do is simply redirect to serverstatus.php while still masking the url which it is doing perfectly well, however serverstatus.php is forced non-ssl i cant change this and a protocol switch from ssl to non-ssl is breaking the url masking.

I could live with this if it was just on this one page, however it isnt. i have other urls masked in the same way some secure some not. and when i click from the none secure into secure or vice-versa i see the same problem cropping up.

I will give you an example.

> Secure-page -> Network-Status/         **URL masking fails (protocol switched)**
>
> Network-Status/ -> Network-Status/       **URL masking works (No protocol Switch)**
>
> Network-Status/ -> Secure-page          **URL masking fails (protocol switch)**

If anybody can help me with this i would be a happy person again, this has taken me the best part of two days of researching and tweaking and trying different things, in the end i can only conclude that this is indeed a direct result of the protocol switch.

If it was an option i would simply force redirect to SSL for all non-SSL connections but this isnt optional at all, there are three key areas where the coding forcing an insecure connection and i cant change it, so whenever these pages are access i end up with a never ending loop.

Comment: How is `serverstatus.php` "forced non-ssl"? What happens, when I request `https://www.example.com/serverstatus.php`?

Comment: http://www.example.com/serverstatus.php Obvioucsy with forced-ssl in the htaccess this is what causes the looping. i dont what causes it, its php i guess there is an immediate location header to switch at the top of the file, its been ioncubed so i cant say but that is what i would have done

Comment: serverstatus.php does a `header(Location:...)` redirect, if it is called with https?

Comment: Yes i would assume so. that is something i cannot turn off as i cant see the code to edit it out.

Comment: No need to add SOLVED into the title...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you must request `Network-Status` (`serverstatus.php`) as HTTP, you can force this yourself first

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule ^Network-Status/$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$0 [R,L,NC]
```

and then do the rewrite afterwards

```
RewriteRule ^Network-Status/$ /serverstatus.php [L,NC]
```

And you can do the same from non-secure to secure for other pages as well.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule ^other-page$ https//%{HTTP_HOST}/$0 [R,L,NC]
RewriteRule ^other-page$ /otherscript.php [L,NC]
```

Comment: I will give that a try now, and see if that fixes the issue with the url. give me 5 minutes and i will know if this has worked.

Comment: I cant yet add reputation to you, but this has sorted the problem out perfectly, Thank you.

Comment: I Just want to add a note to this for anybody using it please make sure you use the whole set on each rewrite, i just tried to use one https condition and found i hit the loops.